# Distance between points in R: distCosine() for a table?

Tags: r, distance

I have a list of position and I would like to know the distances between the closest points. I tried to use distCosine() but there is an issue. Here is what I did:

1. my data, sorted by lat

   ```
   structure(list(lat = c(53.56478, 53.919724, 54.109047, 54.109047, 
   54.36612, 55.48143, 56.2335, 56.682796, 56.93616, 57.804092, 
   58.82089, 59.297623, 59.335075, 59.907795, 60.125046, 60.274445, 
   60.289204, 60.386665, 60.591167, 64.68329), long = c(14.585611, 
   14.286517, 13.807847, 13.807847, 10.997632, 18.182697, 16.454927, 
   16.564703, 18.221214, 23.258204, 17.84381, 18.172949, 18.126884, 
   23.217615, 20.65724, 26.44062, 27.189545, 19.847534, 28.5585, 
   24.534185)), .Names = c("lat", "long"), row.names = c(2L, 3L, 
   6L, 11L, 1L, 17L, 15L, 20L, 13L, 19L, 7L, 14L, 4L, 5L, 10L, 12L, 
   18L, 9L, 8L, 16L), class = "data.frame")
   ```
2. I tried to use distCosine() following an other discussion on stackoverflow to include in a new column the distance from the closest  lat (this is why I sorted by lat):

> data$a<-outer(seq(nrow(data)),
>             seq(nrow(data)),
>             Vectorize(function(i, j) distCosine(data[1,], data[2,]))
>       )

The result does not work... This is not the distance for each point...

is there an easier way to use distCosine for my request?

Comment: I am actually not that far with data$a <- distCosine(p1 = pts[-nrow(pts),], p2 = pts[-1,]) but I have an error since there is nothing for the first line...

Answer (score 1):

I think you just have to replace `distCosine(data[1,], data[2,])` by `distCosine(data[i,c("long","lat")], data[j,c("long","lat")])`:

```
data <- head(data,5)  # smaller example

data$a<-outer( seq(nrow(data)), 
               seq(nrow(data)), 
               Vectorize(
                 function(i, j) distCosine(data[i,c("long","lat")], data[j,c("long","lat")])
                 ) 
               )
```

Result:

```
> data
        lat     long       a.1       a.2       a.3       a.4       a.5
2  53.56478 14.58561      0.00  44146.92  79251.87  79251.87 251291.54
3  53.91972 14.28652  44146.92      0.00  37741.81  37741.81 220118.16
6  54.10905 13.80785  79251.87  37741.81      0.00      0.00 185040.01
11 54.10905 13.80785  79251.87  37741.81      0.00      0.00 185040.01
1  54.36612 10.99763 251291.54 220118.16 185040.01 185040.01      0.00
>
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it with an other function:

```
 data<-data[c("long","lat")]

 distHaversine
 t<-distHaversine(p1 = data[-nrow(data),], 
 p2 = data[-1,]) a<-0 final<-c(a,t) data$dist<-final
 a<-0
 final<-c(a,t)
 data$dist<-final
```